# Distribution of random variable $Y = T - \theta$, where $T$ is a sufficient function for $\theta$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots , X_n$ be a random sample from the distribution with with pdf:
$$
f(x;\theta) = e^{\theta-x} I_{[\theta, +\infty)}, \, \theta \in \mathbb{R}
$$
For the sample we have:
$$
f(x_1, \dots , x_n;\theta) = e^{n\theta} \cdot e^{-\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i} \cdot I(\min x_i  \geq\theta)
$$
Thus, from the **factorization theorem**, $T = \min x_i$ is sufficient for $\theta$.

To find the distribution of $T$, we use the argument that the probability of all $x_i$'s being greater than $x$ is $[1-F(x)]^n$ and thus the CDF of $T$ is $1-[1-F(x)]^n$.

However, what if the random variable involved the parameter $\theta$? Could you give me a hint on how to find the distribution of $Y = T - \theta$?

Comment: In this case you can think of the $X_i$ as being represented as $X_i=\theta+Z_i$ where the $Z_i$ are all exponentially distributed.  Then your $T-\theta$ has a simple expression in terms of the $Z_i$...

Comment: Apart from the above suggestion, you can simply find the CDF of $T-\theta$ like you found the CDF of $T$: $P(T-\theta\le t)=P(T\le t+\theta)=\cdots$

Comment: @StubbornAtom So the answer is simply: $1-[1-F(x+\theta)]^n$?

Comment: Yes, with a shift in the domain of the CDF.